# How can I add TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa) cipher suite to java

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient, tls1.2

I am attempting to add cipher suite "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA" (0xa) to my java HTTPclient however java does not recognize this suite adding Conscrypt as my security provider did offer this cipher suite either.

How would I add this cipher suite to my java list of ciphers?

Comment: Which version of java you are using?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to add it? It is not exactly the best cipher suite out there, see https://ciphersuite.info/cs/TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA/. Why not instead invest time to have proper security enabled? Using TLS with bad/weak ciphers is security theatre not real security.

Comment: You can't unless the JCE provider you're using supports it.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek a site will be able to detect a spoofed useragent in an HTTPS request by seeing if the TLS matches that of which is mentioned in the device the request claims to be. I am attempting to add this cipher to match the tls protocol of Chrome 80.

Comment: @harry I am using Java 8 however I can switch to another version if it would allow me to use this cipher suite.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I set Conscrypt as my security provider, Is there another JCE security provider you would recommend adding which would give me additional ciphersuites to choose from.

Comment: "a site will be able to detect a spoofed useragent in an HTTPS request by seeing if the TLS matches that of which is mentioned in the device the request claims to be." So you mean you artificially lower security for all legit accesses just to be able to detect some impersonation? This is really the wrong way to do that. Anyone can see the ciphers advertised by the client (it is in first message, `ClientHello` and is then in the clear) and then use the same ones. You are not adding any protection that way.

Comment: @PatrickMevzekI want to match chrome fingerprint (match the clienthello in my httpclient)